# MS Access Error 3027 Backend can not be updated

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a Front End and a backend MS Access database application. The Original PC died, so we built a new pc with an ssd HD. installed the new front end on the new PC set up a mapped drive for connecting (via linked tables) to the backend (I've also tried UNC path with same results). We can connect to and log into the backend, just can't do updates from the new pc. I've checked permissions for the user and the group that the user is in has read/write/modify/delete permissions. I even tried my network admin account and I can't even do updates from the new pc from the FE. I've checked the Access default settings and they say shared. Pulling data seems to work fine, as reports work. Drop downs pulling data from the BE database work. We just can't update the BE.

The Error we get is a 3027, Can not update. Database or object is read only. Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: This may not answer your question, but it seems like this would be a great opportunity to switch to a real database backend.  There are several well known problems using Access as a backend for even a low usage app.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, thanks for the suggestion, this is a COTS program out of warranty, so at this time, that is not an option.

Comment: If the app uses ODBC you should be able to adapt the connection to a MSSQL database transparently.  If you bought an app that doesn't use ODBC, regrettably, you're pretty much out of luck, and frankly it's what the company deserves for being so cheap.  You should make sure the Access application is installed on your server.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer The access BackEnd seems fine for the other 3 access Frontends. Its just the 1 newest frontend install that has an issue with the 1 form. I've checked permissions and trust and at this point am just out of ideas on what the actual issue might be. Thanks in advance .

Comment: This is neither about using another database as the backend, ODBC (which is not used here), nor having Access installed on the server (which certainly isn't required). It is a permission issue somehow. Check, that Access as able to create the lockfile (backendfilename.laccdb). Also, double-check the rights for the user accounts - does every user account cause the same behaviour on all workstations? Finally, double-check that you have the newest Windows patches installed (Check for updates), as well as Office updates as there recently have been some serious issues when sharing Access databases.

Comment: It was permissions. done, Thanks all.